# How do I OrderBy a DateTime difference in Linq?

Tags: linq, datetime

I have a table with a `CreatedDate` column. I want to order by the rows that have been in the database the longest, but need to determine the number of days by subtracting it from `DateTime.Now`.

I realise this is doable simply by ordering by the `CreatedDate`, but I need to do more than that.

I need to order the items by the amount of times they have been used within a period of time, in effect getting the most popular items.

So what I want to do is first determine the number of days, and after that divide this by the number of times each item has been used.

Step 1)

```
orderby (DateTime.Now.Subtract(t.CreatedDate.Value).Days)
```

Step 2)

```
orderby (t.UsedCount/DateTime.Now.Subtract(t.CreatedDate.Value).Days)
```

This results in the following error:

> Method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)' has no supported translation to SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Oddly, "Subtract()" doesn't work, but Minus does.
try:

```
 orderby (t.UsedCount/(DateTime.Now - t.CreatedDate.Value).Days)
```

(Tested in LINQPad using the "master" database)

```
from sp in Spt_monitors
orderby sp.Io_busy / (DateTime.Now - sp.Lastrun).Days
select sp
```